# How to show this line is tangent to $f$ at point $a$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:I\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable function, with $f'(a)\neq 0$ for some $a$ in the interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$. If there exists a line $L\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a sequence $(x_k)$ in $I$such that $x_i\neq x_j$ when $i\neq j$, $\lim x_k=a$ and $f(x_k)\in L$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then $L$ is the tangent line to $f$ at point $a$.

This is what I've tried: the tangent line to $f$ at point $a$ is the set $T=\{f(a)+tf'(a);\;\;t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. So, it's needed to show that $L=T$. Suppose that $L=\{u+tv;\;\;t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $t_k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_k)=u+t_kv$. Moreover there exists $t_a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(a)=u+t_av$. Thus

$$f'(a)=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(a)}{x_k-a}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{(u+t_kv)-(u+t_av)}{x_k-a}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\left(0u+\frac{t_k-t_a}{x_k-a}v\right)$$

Since $f$ is differentiable, it's continuous. So, $\lim f(x_k)=f(a)$.

Therefore, we know that $f'(a),f(a)\in L$ (because $L$ is closed).
Could someone give me a hint to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most of the pieces, you just have to arrange them correctly.  To use your language, we need to show that $L=\{u+tv;\;\;t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ satisfies $f(a)\in L$ and $v$ is parallel to $f'(a)$.

---

#### proof that $f(a)\in L$:

Note that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=a$.  Since $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous, which is to say that $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=f(a)$.  Since $f(x_k)\in L$ for each $k$, we know that $f(a)$ is a limit point of $L$.  Since $L$ is closed, $f(a)\in L$.  Thus, there is some $t_a$ so that $L(t_a)=f(a)$.

---

#### proof that $v$ is parallel to $f'(a)$:

As you stated,
$$
f'(a)=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(a)}{x_k-a}
$$
However, since each $f(x_k)\in L$, we can also say that
$$
\begin{align}
L'(a)&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(a)}{t_k-t_a}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{f(x_k)-f(a)}{x_k-a}\cdot\frac{x_k-a}{t_k-t_a}\\
&=f'(a)\cdot \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{x_k-a}{t_k-t_a}
\end{align}
$$
Since $L'(t)=v$, we deduce that $v$ is a scalar multiple of $f'(a)$, which means that the two vectors are parallel.

Comment: Where did you use $f'(a)\neq 0$?

Comment: The vector equality implicitly does so.  If $f'(a)$ were $0$, we wouldn't be able to say anything about the direction of $L'(a)$

Comment: Where did you use $x_i\neq x_j$ if $i\neq j$?

Comment: I didn't. It is sufficient that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=a$

Comment: How do you know that the sequence $(x_k-a)/(t_k-t_a)$ converges?

Comment: If it didn't converge, then by the above equality $L'(a)$ wouldn't exist.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. In this passage $\lim\frac{f(x_k)-f(a)}{x_k-a}\cdot\frac{x_k-a}{t_k-t_a}=f'(a)\cdot \lim \frac{x_k-a}{t_k-t_a}$ you used that if $\lim z_k \alpha_k$ exists and $\lim z_k$ exists then $\lim \alpha_k$ exists and $\lim z_k\alpha_k=\lim z_k\lim\alpha_k$. Is this your argument for the existence of $\lim \frac{x_k-a}{t_k-t_a}$?

Comment: Yes, exactly, as long as the limits of the product is non-zero.

Comment: In the equality $\lim\frac{f(x_k)-f(a)}{t_k-t_a}=\lim\frac{f(x_k)-f(a)}{x_k-a}\cdot\frac{x_k-a}{t_k-t_a}$ are you using $x_k\neq a$? I think so, but you said that it's sufficient $\lim x_k=a$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. You are right, you can only say that using the fact that $x_k\neq a$